# What C++17 standard say about calling delete on nullptr?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, delete-operator, nullptr

C++03 Standard say's:

> **5.3.5 Delete**
>
> [...] In either alternative, if the value of the operand of delete is the null pointer the operation has no effect.[...]

```
char *p = nullptr;
delete p; //no effect
```

It means, it is valid to delete null pointer in c++.

What C++17 standard say about calling delete on nullptr pointer?

Comment: NULL is an integer. You should initialize pointers with `nullptr`.

Comment: @PiotrKocia i did correction. Thanks.

Comment: @PiotrKocia NULL or 0 is valid for pointer initialization. nullptr doesn't exist in C++03.

Comment: @manni66 is valid, but passing NULL to template == bugs. It's a bad practice to use NULL. `nullptr` should be used instead. The question is tagged `c++1z`, not `c++03`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it is valid, and it results in a noop. [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete)

> If expression evaluates to a null pointer value, no destructors are called, and the deallocation function is not called.

Answer (score 7):

For destructors, [[expr.delete]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#6.sentence-1):

> If the value of the operand of the *delete-expression* is not a null pointer value, the *delete-expression* will invoke the destructor (if any) for the object or the elements of the array being deleted.

This technically doesn't say that if the operand *is* a null pointer value, the destructor isn't invoked. Probably a minor wording issue?

For deallocation, [[expr.delete]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#7.sentence-3):

> If the value of the operand of the delete-expression is a null pointer value, **it is unspecified** whether a deallocation function will be called as described above.

Unspecified deallocation, but likely no destruction.

Note also, from [[basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#stc.dynamic.deallocation-3.sentence-2), which clarifies that even if the standard library deallocation function is called in this situation, there is no effect:

> The value of the first argument supplied to a deallocation function may be a null pointer value; if so, and if the deallocation function is one supplied in the standard library, the call has no effect.

Comment: The deallocation function might or might not be called, but if it is called and it has not been overridden by the user, it does nothing. 6.6.4.4.2 "The value of the first argument supplied to a deallocation function may be a null pointer value; if so, and if the deallocation function is one supplied in the standard library, the call has no effect."